# How to delete older blocks in a private blockchain network?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, memory

I would like to delete the old blocks when the memory is full in blocks. I understand that there will be loss of some data due to the deleting the blocks. But I think it would not change the structure of the blockchain.

I want to know how to implement it. I am using go-ethereum.

Answer (score 1):

In blockchain there is now way of deleting the old blocks. The only suggested way is to increase the memory of the hard disk.

So when you develop the blockchain based application you should consider some architecture which will help to to store less memory in blockchain.

History of the blocks are the core logic behind the blockchain.

Comment: but deletng the first few blocks and changing the genesis block would still retain the basic blockchain structure, right?

Comment: No it will not. If any block is deleted subsequent blocks will become invalid, because every next block is linked with previous block's hash value.